# Datastore: DatastoreFailureException: Unable to fetch global config

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Has anyone ever had this error before? I can't find a single shred of evidence on google that this has ever happened to anyone.

Here is the stacktrace which starts from a .delete() call on the datastore.

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreFailureException: Unable to fetch global config
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:129)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$7.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:406)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$7.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:402)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.delete(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:76)
    at com.universeprojects.cacheddatastore.CachedDatastoreService.delete(CachedDatastoreService.java:929)
```

Comment: (1) Which library are you using? (2) Do you call it from App Engine, Compute Engine, or somewhere else?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I'm using the built in datastore API. I'm calling from Appengine on a frontend instance.

Pretty weird eh?

Comment: I started receiving this error today, I'm using Python ndb to access datastore.  It seems to be an internal google error, my code hasn't change and I use GAE since 4 years ago.

Comment: We're investigating - this is 2 different errors being conflated as one. The first is as @Joshua-melcon answers, we're looking into the second.

Comment: @DanMcGrath saw this again last night 10/3/16 at 21:49 UTC . Is  this still an ongoing issue? Are others seeing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently identified an issue with a bad instance in our infrastructure which caused timeouts for a limited number of configuration requests from AppEngine applications. The issue was resolved when the faulty instance was restarted ~6:00 AM Pacific Time 9/20/2016.

To prevent these errors in the future we are taking the following actions:

1. Modifying the retry behavior for configuration requests to better
   handle individual bad instances.
2. Implementing stricter monitoring
   policies around these instances to better detect these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the [Key.getAppId](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.java?r=512#278) portion of the key you are trying to delete is set identically to any [Key.getAppId](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key.java?r=512#278) that you have read from Datastore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this error suddenly without changes to code or models, it happens in three different apps.
As this error happens to many users, in Python and in Java, I think is due to internal google's datastore code or updates.

```
InternalError: Unable to fetch global config
at check_rpc_success (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py:1373)
at __query_result_hook (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py:2906)
at get_result (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py:613)
at _on_rpc_completion (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:513)
at _run_to_list (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py:995)
at _help_tasklet_along (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:427)
at get_result (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py:383)
at fetch (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py:1218)
at positional_wrapper (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py:160)
```

I raised this error to Google Cloud Platform support team, when I have news I will post them here.